Bibliographic Reference on Filled-In Julia Sets
Good morning!
I'm looking for a book that provides some mathematical information on filled-in Julia sets.

I don’t have much background knowledge in fractals, so I’d prefer something introductory.

On the other hand, I’d rather avoid something overly simplistic, meaning I’m looking for more than just graphical representations.


The reason I’m searching for such a resource is that I’m working on a master’s thesis in logistic mapping. A section of a chapter will focus on its complex version, which means I’ll need some information on filled-in Julia sets.
I have already reviewed the following books, and they did not seem satisfactory, as they were either too simplistic or did not mention anything about filled-in Julia sets, only Julia sets (and even that briefly).

"Chaos and Fractals: New Frontiers of Science" by Heinz-Otto Peitgen, Hartmut Jürgens, and Dietmar Saupe.

"The Beauty of Fractals" by Heinz-Otto Peitgen and Peter H. Richter.

"The Beauty of Fractals" by Denny Gulick and Jon Scott.


Thank you in advance!
